# How to add custom logging to TrackJS

Tags: trackjs

I have a page redirect happening on a certain page that I need to watch for in an angular 5 app. I need to get the url while it is happening. How / Where can I add such things in TrackJs. Which API should I be using

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to instrument the destination page and log the referrer so that you know the source, or add a hook before navigation occurs and check the destination.

For a hook, you'll need to know how the navigation happens: either a click, form post, or window.open. For each of these, you can add an eventListener to look for the event and log.

You'll utilize the standard TrackJS API to `track()` a custom error when the right event occurs.